# PySpark and Raster (GeoTiff) data

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark, gdal, geotiff

I'm trying to use Spark (PySpark) to in order to run analysis on data stored in multi-band GeoTiffs. I'm still somewhat of a Spark newbie.

---

*Setup*:

The geotiffs themselves are small enough to run in pure python - specifically I am using gdal to read the data. I then create dataframes and do the analysis.

However the analysis takes awhile. And, on a recurring basis, I will have hundreds of geotiffs to analyze  - enter PySpark.

---

*Problem*:

I've written code that allows me to run the analysis on a local pseudo-cluster. However it fails with proper cluster because the data stored on the master node can not be read locally by the worker nodes.

HDFS should come to the rescue, however `sc.textFile(..)` returns the raw unprocessed content of the geotiff which isn't very useful.

I could preprocess the data to turn the geotiffs into csv's but the additional overhead might make it not worthwhile.

The two solutions I had hope to find were

- A spark method, lets call it `sc.rasterFile(...)`, which would read a geotiff into a spark data frame or rdd
- The ability to access hdfs from pure python methods. Something like ~

  `gdal.Open("hdfs://...", gc.GA_ReadOnly)`

---

*Questions*:

1. Am I correct to assume that neither of the above solutions are possible?
2. Are there other tools/methods/apis for working with tiffs in Spark?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and process whole files the simplest approach is to combine `binaryFiles` and `io` module:

```py
from io import BytesIO

(sc
    .binaryFiles(path)
    .values()
    .map(BytesIO)
    .map(some_function_which_expects_opened_binary_file))
```

Regarding your remaining queries:

- There is no `sc.rasterFile` but there are some image processing input formats provided by [Hipi](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/) which can be used in Spark with `SparkContext.hadoopFile`.
- It is possible to read directly from Posix compliant distributed file system or even HDFS (for example with [`hdfs3`](https://github.com/dask/hdfs3)) but these methods won't take into account data locality and can result in suboptimal performance.